# How to allow users to turn add to timeline posts on/off?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I am building an app that uses the Add to Timeline functionality to post to a users wall. However, now I want to allow the user to decide if they want to post to their wall or not; essentially an on/off add-to-timeline toggle. Any ideas?

For example, if they are reading a news story - the user can decide if they want to post using add-to-timeline or not. Dailymotion has this when logged in using your facebook account and viewing a video. Right below the video shows a 'Social On' with a preview of what will be posted to your timeline.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at how social reader apps do this. We worked with all the launch apps do design privacy controls that let you enable/disable posting activity to timeline, or remove a recent specific activity.

Here's more from the Guardian's FAQ's: http://www.guardian.co.uk/help/insideguardian/2011/sep/22/the-guardian-on-facebook-app

And from The Independent: http://www.independent.co.uk/news/media/online/recently-read-on-the-independent-2359683.html

Technically, its a switch within your app which decides if you make the post to FB or not. If you want to allow the user to permenently remove your ability to publish Timeline, you can perform an HTTP DELETE on

https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions/publish_actions

and the permission will be programmatically revoked.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The examples are helpful and demonstrate what I am trying to do. What functionality exists in facebook to temporarily disable posting to a users wall - not permanently disabling. I'm having difficulty figuring out how to temporarily shut off the add to timeline posts based on the users request (ie clicking 'Social Off').